# Open menu when long press icon outside application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When long pressed how to show the options? Searched for a clue but could not get any resources to start with. How can I achieve [image].

Comment: I don't think this is solvable with flutter. Instead, you have to do something in native Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [quick_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_actions) plugin by the flutter team

and here is the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLxjbJtI_2w)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the android's official documentation to create shortcut
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts